# Не создается INI-файл

Tags: delphi, ini

Скажите, в чем может быть проблема? Где моя ошибка?

Руководствуясь, http://code-code.narod.ru/art/ini.html , я сделал все, как указано там. А именно:

1. Создал проект.
2. В uses добавил модуль IniFiles.
3. Далее объявил глобальную переменную `IniFile: TIniFile;`.
4. Ну и сделал так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Button1 создавался ini-файл:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     IniFile:=TIniFile.Create('D:\test\settings.ini');
   end;
   ```

Ошибок или предупреждений при компиляции нету.

Comment: Ты нажимал на кнопку?

Comment: Разумеется.

Comment: Просто в файл ничего не добавили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это рабочий пример из моего проекта. В ini хранятся настройки подключения к базе MySql. Попробуй так, все это разметив в коде событие нажатия кнопки. Файл будет создан там, откуда запущена прога.

> ```
> Var
>   Ini : TIniFile;
> Begin
>   Ini := nil;
>   try
>   Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\settings.ini');
>   Ini.WriteString('mysql','basa',BaseName);
>   Ini.WriteString('mysql','login',BaseLogin);
>   Ini.WriteString('mysql','pass',BasePass);
>   Ini.WriteString('mysql','host',BaseAddress);
>   Ini.WriteString('any','prz',Punkt);
>   Ini.WriteString('any','rewrite',ReWriteIni);
>   Ini.Free;
>   Except
>    ShowMessage('Не удается сохранить настройки в файл : '+
> ```
>
> Ini.FileName);
>       end;

Сегодня сяду набросаю нормальный пример статьи. Смотри поже на myshinobi.ru. Если что не пойдет, напиши здесь же.

**Обновление**

Вы вместо переменных `BaseName,BaseLogin` указали значения? Так как переменные пустые, то по умолчанию файл пустой, поэтому может и не создает, как отмечалось выше в комментарии... Потому как он просто не может сохранить пустоту.

Чтобы не быть голословным, могу приложить сорцы. Напиши мыло, куда скинуть. Или вот смотри, поробуй вот так:

```
 Var
  Ini : TIniFile;
Begin
  Ini := nil;
  try
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName)+'\settings.ini');
  Ini.WriteString('mysql','basa','sdfsdf');
  Ini.WriteString('mysql','login','sdfsdf');
  Ini.WriteString('mysql','pass','asdadas');
  Ini.WriteString('mysql','host','Ddsafdsfs');

  Ini.Free;
  Except
   ShowMessage('Не удается сохранить настройки в файл : '+
Ini.FileName); end;
```

У меня отлично все отработало. Результат:

```
basa=sdfsdf
login=sdfsdf
pass=asdadas
host=Ddsafdsfs
```

Comment: также, не создается.

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо. :)

Comment: Да рад был помочь)